# Reshape the dataset

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I am reshaping my dataset for running HLM in the  lme4 package.

I mainly tried the melt function in the reshape2 package and other functions in the dplyr package. However, they did not give me what I want.

Here is the dataset that I have now:

```
ID    Totalscore Gender SA3B  SB3C  SJJD  SUAB
0511  390        F      1     NA    NA    NA
0522  340        M      NA    0     NA    NA
0533  180        F      NA    1     0     NA
0782  301        M      NA    NA    NA    1
```

ID is examinee ID. "SAEB, SB3C, SJJD, SUAB" are items on a test. There are more than 3000 items and not each examinee see every item. 1 indicates a correct answer, and 0 otherwise. Therefore, there are many NA in the datasets.

This is the reshaped dataset that I aim to obtain:

```
Examinee      0511   0522  0533  0533  0782
Total Score   390    340   180   180   301
Gender        F      M     F     F     M
Item          SA3B   SB3C  SB3C  SJJD  SUAB
Itemscore     1      0     1     0     1
```

The difficulty on my end is that different examinees see different numbers of items, and in the final dataset that I want to obtain, there should be no NAs because everything is contained (nothing dropped) in the reshaped dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt` and then filter out rows with `NA` values:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(reshape2);

melt(df, id.vars = c("ID", "Totalscore", "Gender"), 
         variable.name = "Item", value.name = "Itemscore") %>% 
filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% t %>% data.frame

#              X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
# ID          511  522  533  533  782
# Totalscore  390  340  180  180  301
# Gender        F    M    F    F    M
# Item       SA3B SB3C SB3C SJJD SUAB
# Itemscore     1    0    1    0    1
```

Comment: @Frank Yep. Forget about loading the packages. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Psidom, thank you for your answer. But in my original dataset, there are no variables called "Item" and "Itemscore". Guess that is where I found difficult.

Comment: The dataset is what it looks like in the post : )

Comment: `Item` and `Itemscore` are columns created when you transform your dataset from wide to long. Since your result contains the two rows, I renamed the variable and value names.

Comment: I understand now. It worked! My apologies for the confusion. Thank you so much!!! Psidom!!

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be just confusion over formatting, but if I take the transformed data set you posted above literally (i.e. different variables in different *rows* of the data set), it is *not* a form that will actually be useful for HLM fitting with `lme4`; you need variables as columns.  On the other hand, that may be what you meant, in which case the only advantage of my solution over @Psidom's is that you only need `reshape2::melt` and `na.omit` from base R, no tools (pipes, `dplyr`, etc.) beyond that.

I would do this:

```
## get data
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
ID    Totalscore Gender SA3B  SB3C  SJJD  SUAB
0511  390        F      1     NA    NA    NA
0522  340        M      NA    0     NA    NA
0533  180        F      NA    1     0     NA
0782  301        M      NA    NA    NA    1")

library(reshape2)
na.omit(melt(dd,id.vars=1:3,value.name="Itemscore",
             variable.name="Item"))

##     ID Totalscore Gender     Item Itemscore
## 1  511        390      F     SA3B     1
## 6  522        340      M     SB3C     0
## 7  533        180      F     SB3C     1
## 11 533        180      F     SJJD     0
## 16 782        301      M     SUAB     1
```

Then you could do something like

```
glmer(Itemscore~Gender+Totalscore+ (1|ID/Item) + (1|Item),
      family="binomial")
```

...

Comment: Hi Ben. Thank you SO MUCH for your help on this!! The dataset I was looking at is the `"InstEval" ` dataset in the lme4 package. `str(InstEval)`. I think the way you present the datase is a transpose version of mine. Am I correct?`

Comment: I think this is mostly a formatting/presentation confusion. Compare `str(InstEval)` (which prints each *element* in the list) with `head(InstEval)` - yes, mine is transposed from yours.